# How do I stop Blender 2.8 from quitting when I close a project?

Tags: interface

I was working on a throw away project (a tutorial) and decided I wanted to try a different one. I closed the project, said I didn't want to save it, and it closed, but so did Blender. A bunch of macOS utilities do this, but IMHO it's a terrible choice for a major application.

How can I make that stop? I can't find anything in the preferences.

Comment: Blender doesn't handle multiple projects at the same time like GIMP. Just click on File>New if you want to throw away the project and want to create an other one.

Comment: I'm only familiar with the Windows version, but do you happen to have an option to create a new scene? In Windows, the command is File->New->* to begin a blank (default) scene.

Comment: Just open the next project directly. You may be asked if you want to save the current project or not, if not discard changes and choose the next project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You cannot stop Blender from quitting when you close a project

I'm afraid, it does not work the way you wish it to work. Blender cannot be opened without some file loaded and it can open only one file at a time. If the file is closed, Blender is closed as well. Even when you start Blender for the first time it loads a file - that is the default scene. You can open multiple instances of Blender with different files. Then if you close one, all the other open instances will remain open. This is just how it works.

You can have multiple scenes in a file and they can have completely different settings - they can even use different render engines for example, only one scene in an open file can be active at a time, but you can switch between them without closing the file or the instance of Blender.

Comment: I didn't ask for it to open more than one file. I wanted the application itself to stay open when I close a project, so I can then open the next one.

Comment: It cannot be opened without some file loaded.

Comment: @HackSaw then just open the next file you want, if the current one is saved it will just close, if not you get a warning to save it. You don't need to keep the application open with no files.

Comment: That also sounds logical to me. Closing a project is an unnecessary step before opening another. It will just close by itself. If I want to have an empty scene for something messy, for example importing stuff that I have no idea what I am going to get with, I just create a new scene, then delete it when finished. Works fine for me.

Comment: Fair enough. It's a bit surprising, but I can't honestly say it's important, given the one-at-a-time nature of things.